# How to avoid using react useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am hearing term "Avoid using `useEffect()` in your react app".

I tried to look for the answers but could not find anything which answers specifically what should I use instead of useEffect?

For example consider below cases.

1. I have to fetch data from server when component loads? what should I use instead of useEffect?
2. I have to perform some operation on state change? how can i detect state change and perform that action..
3. I have 2 components say header and body both sharing a global state... lets say header has a dropdown and I have to perform some operation in body component when that dropdown value changes.... how can I capture the change in state in body component?

How can I avoid using useEffect or am I asking wrong question? perhaps I should ask what is the right way to use useEffect?

Answer (score 1):

Using `useEffect` is perfectly alright. Although, you need to take care of dependencies and make sure it isn't called unnecessarily.

Going through your cases one by one,

1. You can use `useQuery`, it is much more refined for this particular use-case.
   https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery
2. You can use `useEffect`. It is perfectly alright.
3. For this case, using state management libraries would be better, example would be `zustand`, `redux`, etc.

All the mentioned libraries, make your life easier and less prone to errors. However, that doesn't mean they replace `useEffect`. There are infinite cases where `useEffect` can and should be used.

For the last question, how to properly use `useEffect` I would suggest going through React documentation. They are pretty niche.

https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

Comment: For case #3 you don't need a state management library. Lift the state up and leverage useReducer and custom Hook. If you really need the state far in your app, context should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in rare cases the `useEffect` is needed and for examples you mentioned above:

1. For fetching data using `react-query` will be much better https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query
2. You can avoid using a `useEffect` by going to the action where the change event is happening and doing the operation directly there. example `<input name="firstName" onChange={...the change event is happening here.. } />`
3. This is a bit similar to the point number 2 answer

When you using a `useEffect` always ask yourself if you really need it and try to see other possibilities.